# Validate fantasy football lineup with given parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given the following object lineup:

```
var lineup = [
  {
    "Name": "Matt Ryan",
    "Team": "ATL",
    "Position": "QB"
  },{
    "Name": "Devonte Freeman",
    "Team": "ATL",
    "Position": "RB"
  }, {
    "Name": "Jahvid Best",
    "Team": "DET",
    "Position": "RB"
  }, {
    "Name": "Calvin Johnson",
    "Team": "DET",
    "Position": "WR"
  },{
    "Name": "Julio Jones",
    "Team": "ATL",
    "Position":"WR"
  }, {
    "Name": "Julian Edelman",
    "Team": "NE",
    "Position": "WR"
  }, {
    "Name": "Kyle Rudolph",
    "Team": "MIN",
    "Position": "TE"
  }, {
    "Name": "Jordy Nelson",
    "Team": "GB",
    "Position": "WR"
  }, {
    "Name": "Cincinatti Bengals",
    "Team": "CIN",
    "Position": "DST"
  }
];
```

Evaluate the lineup and return true if valid and false elsewise under the requirements:

```
//rule 1: must use 9 players
//rule 2: must use a roster spanning 2 games
//rule 3: Must fit to position requirements
//rule 4: Limit maximum number of players from one team to 4

var validateLineup(lineup){
    var posReq = positionRequirement(lineup);  //checks rule 1 and 3
    var validGames = checkValidGames(lineup); //check rule 2
    var maxPlayers = checkMaxPlayers(lineup); //check rule 4
    return posReq && validGames && maxPlayers;
}

var checkMaxPlayers(lineup){
    var teamDict = [];
    var maxTeam = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < lineup.length; i++){
      for (var j = 1; j < lineup.length; j++){
        if (lineup[i].Team === lineup[j].Team){
          maxTeam++;
        }
      }
      if (maxTeam > 3) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

var checkValidGames(lineup){
  var arrTeams = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < lineup.length; i++){
    if (!lineup[i].Team in arrTeams ){
      arrTeams.push(lineup[i].Team);
    }
  }
  if (arrTeams.length >= 2) return true;
  else return false;
}

//O(N) time complexity O(1) space
var positionRequirement(lineup){
  var noQB, noRB, noWR, noTE, noDST = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < lineup.length; i++){
    if (lineup[i].Position === "QB"){
      noQB++;
    }
    else if (lineup[i].Position === "RB"){
      noRB++;
    }
    else if (lineup[i].Position === "WR"){
      noWR++;
    }
    else if (lineup[i].Position === "TE"){
      noTE++;
    }
    else if (lineup[i].Position === "DST"){
      noDST++;
    }
  }

  if (noQB != 1) return false;
  else if (noRB > 3 || noRB < 2) return false;
  else if (noWR > 4 || noWR < 3) return false;
  else if (noTE > 2 || noTE < 1) return false;
  else if (noDST != 1) return false;

  if (noQB+noRB+noWR+noTE+noDST === 9) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

I believe everything should be okay except I don't particularly like the function where I check for max players in one team. If it was any other language I feel like using a map would be faster but because it's javascript, initializing a dictionary and then evaluating seems like it'll be slower than just doing a O(N^2) loop. Code check and further improvement tips would be appreciated

Comment: Questions like this where you have working code that you want to optimize are better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. You could optimize this whole thing down to a single `reduce()`  that produces an object with all the various validation properties without having to iterate array for each property

Comment: var noQB, noRB, noWR, noTE, noDST = 0; just sets noDST to 0

Answer (score 1):

Using an object like a dictionary, loop through the data once and add the teams to the object's key if it does not exist and increment the value for that team if it exists.

Loop through the list of keys and if any of their values is greater than 4, return false.

```
function checkMaxPlayers(lineup)
{
    var team = [];

    lineup.forEach(el => {
        
        if(Object.keys(team).includes(el.Team))
        {
            team[el.Team]++;
        }
        else
        {
            team[el.Team] = 1;
        }
    });


   for(let key of Object.entries(team))
   {
       if(key[1]>4)
       {
           return false;
       }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, objects work like a map. So you can go through your data and get distinct teams with it's players in linear time.

Answer (score 0):

checkMaxPlayers function has a fix I guess maxTeam must be reset to 0 after each inner loop, here is the fix:

```
 var checkMaxPlayers(lineup){
    var teamDict = [];
    var maxTeam = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < lineup.length; i++){
      for (var j = 1; j < lineup.length; j++){
        if (lineup[i].Team === lineup[j].Team){
          maxTeam++;
        }
      }
      if (maxTeam > 4) 
      {
         return false;
      }
      else
      {
        maxTeam=0; 
      }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All 3 functions had slight problems, here is a fix for each of them. They now all return true with the given list

```
//rule 1: must use 9 players
//rule 2: must use a roster spanning 2 games
//rule 3: Must fit to position requirements
//rule 4: Limit maximum number of players from one team to 4

function validateLineup(lineup){
    var posReq = positionRequirement(lineup);  //checks rule 1 and 3
    var validGames = checkValidGames(lineup); //check rule 2
    var maxPlayers = checkMaxPlayers(lineup); //check rule 4
    return posReq && validGames && maxPlayers;
}

//O(N) time complexity O(1) space
function positionRequirement(lineup){
  var noQB = noRB = noWR = noTE = noDST = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < lineup.length; i++){
    if (lineup[i].Position === "QB"){
      noQB++;
    }
    else if (lineup[i].Position === "RB"){
      noRB++;
    }
    else if (lineup[i].Position === "WR"){
      noWR++;
    }
    else if (lineup[i].Position === "TE"){
      noTE++;
    }
    else if (lineup[i].Position === "DST"){
      noDST++;
    }
  }

  if (noQB != 1) return false;
  else if (noRB > 3 || noRB < 2) return false;
  else if (noWR > 4 || noWR < 3) return false;
  else if (noTE > 2 || noTE < 1) return false;
  else if (noDST != 1) return false;

  if (noQB+noRB+noWR+noTE+noDST === 9) return true;
  else return false;
}

function checkValidGames(lineup){
  var arrTeams = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < lineup.length; i++){
    if (!arrTeams.includes(lineup[i].Team) ){
      arrTeams.push(lineup[i].Team);
    }
  }
  
  if (arrTeams.length >= 2) return true;
  else return false;
}

function checkMaxPlayers(lineup){
    var teamMap = {};
    var maxTeam = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < lineup.length; i++){
        teamMap[lineup[i].Team] = 0;
    }
    
    for (var i = 0; i < lineup.length; i++){
        teamMap[lineup[i].Team]++;
        if(teamMap[lineup[i].Team] > maxTeam){
          maxTeam = teamMap[lineup[i].Team]
        } 
    }
    
    if (maxTeam > 3) return false;
    return true;
}
```